# Git list of Files with more than 'n' modifications of last commit with respect to current dirty state

Tags: git, github, diff, bitbucket.org, commit

With a huge repository, it becomes challenging to track changes.

`Github` displays one statistic per file (total number of lines modified; includes add or deleted as well). Can we list that statistics (just one number) per file for all the files (of the repository) in the dirty state (uncommitted and unstaged) with respect to the last commit locally in the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly - the best approximation is

```
git diff --numstat
```

which gives two numbers: the number of added and deleted lines. You can add up these two numbers with like this:

```
git diff --numstat | awk -F '\t' '{print $1+$2, $3}'
```

The diff will be done between the working tree and the index. You can optionally add the `diff` option `--cached` for index vs HEAD comparison and just `HEAD` for working tree vs HEAD comparison. But "working tree vs HEAD minus index" - as I understand your question - is not possible.

So the complete commands are:

```
git diff --numstat --cached | awk -F '\t' '{print $1+$2, $3}'
git diff --numstat HEAD | awk -F '\t' '{print $1+$2, $3}'
```

Comment: In this `git diff --numstat | awk -F '\t' '{print $1+$2, $3}'`, do we need to specify filename or we just need to run it anywhere in the repository location

Comment: By default git will show you all changed files.

Comment: `git status ` shows 2 files deleted. `git diff --numstat` shows nothing

Comment: Ah, deleted files are indeed not show in `--numstat`, only deleted lines.

Comment: That's because `deleted`  files are already in the index. So you must use the variant with `HEAD` in that case.